# Compare string with select statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, function

i have to make a function in mysql that returns 0 or 1.

```
DELIMITER //
drop function compruebacuenta//
CREATE FUNCTION compruebacuenta(ncliente INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE fin int default 0;
DECLARE cuenta varchar(30);
DECLARE cliente varchar(30);
DECLARE cuentacliente varchar(30);
select codigo_cliente FROM clientes where codigo_cliente=ncliente into   cuentacliente;
RETURN fin;
END;
//
```

user gives a number when calling the function i.e `select function(1);`
what i do then is get the cod for a client with that given code (I know a bit redundant , but whatever); and store it in a variable called `cuentacliente`;
What i need to do now is get a query like this one

```
select cod_cliente from cuentas;
```

store that in another and I want to know how can I compare lets say a 10 , to see if there's a 10 in the resulting query.

I'm thinking that perhaps i need a cursor that fetches each row and compare that with what's in `cuentacliente`.

Comment: Your question contains several unexplained columns and it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you post a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with an example table(s) layout?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af7608/2      Basically i want to input a client with the function , lets say 5  that 5 is from table cuentas , then i want to get all the codes from the table clientes , and check that that client has an account , return 1 if he indeed has one and 0 if he doesn't have an account in the system , the querys are from 2 different tables.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to test if the number you input is both in `cuentas.cod_cliente` and `clientes.codigo_cliente`. What's keeping you from doing a `INNER JOIN` using the `ncliente` as a `WHERE` condition and testing if it returns anything (see [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af7608/15) example)?